# How to migrate column data to new data type

Tags: oracle

I need to migrate table's column to another data type with some modifications. Given: table 'USER' with column 'ORDER_TIME' (DateTime format). It's required to change column type to NUMBER, convert that time to a minutes (e.g. 8:00 AM = 480 mins.) and to store new value. As i understand, i need to create new column with required NUMBER data type, iterate over all records, do some recalculations, store new value, drop old column and rename new one to an actual name. So, basically, algorithm is:

```
ALTER TABLE USER ADD ORDER_TIME_MINS NUMBER(4) NULL;
```

*iteration and recalculation*

```
ALTER TABLE USER 
DROP COLUMN ORDER_TIME
RENAME COLUMN ORDER_TIME_MINS TO ORDER_TIME;
```

Can you suggest me some reading on how that iteration may looks like?

Comment: `8:00 AM = 4800 mins` No it is equal to `8:00 AM = 480 mins`

Comment: Rahul Tripathi, It was just a typo :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
update tablename
set columnName = to_number(to_char(to_date(yourDateColumn,'hh24:mi:ss'),'sssss'))/60
```

And if your time is in format 08:00 PM then like

```
update tablename
set columnName =TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('08:00 AM','HH:MI AM'),'SSSSS'))/60
```

Rest of the steps which you have shown ie, dropping and renamin are fine.

Comment: One thing: it looks like i don't need to_date, since my original date already have DateTime type.

Comment: It works great. Thanks a lot. I just used extract() instead that mentioned sequence of to_number -> to_char -> to_date.

Comment: @psed:- Glad to help you!